# SQL - compare part of word in WHERE clausule

Tags: sql

I have problem with sql query.

For example, I have table like this:

```
ID Name1 Name2 Country
1  Greg  Torr  Poland
2  John  Smith England
3  Tom   Jerry USA
```

I want get all record, which have for example, "la" in Country. In this case:
PoLAnd
EngLAnd

How I can put this in Where clausule?

Greets

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can use the Like Clause here. The examples are available on

- http://www.sql-tutorial.net/SQL-LIKE.asp
- http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp

etc.

Comment: I know about this site ;) But i don't have much time for reading all of operators in WHERE clausule

Comment: Yes, I understand. But I didn't know what operator I am looking for. Now I know

Answer (score 4):

Use the LIKE keyword:

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE Country LIKE '%la%'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
WHERE CHARINDEX('LA', Country) > 0
```

alternatively

```
WHERE Country LIKE '%la%'
```

Comment: `CHARINDEX` may not work in all DBMS. `LIKE` should work in all.

Answer (score 1):

If your RDBMS is case-sensitive, convert `Country` to upper case using the appropriate string function, and compare against the upper case `LA` with a `LIKE`:

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl
WHERE UPPER(Country) LIKE '%LA%'
```

Answer (score 1):

Enclose your keyword before and after with `Percent Symbol`

```
SELECT *
FROM tableName
WHERE Country LIKE '%LA%'
```